# How to print PDF documents with a CMYK color profile from LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, cmyk

I would like to print to PDF documents from LibreOffice Writer but with CMYK color profiles.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [LibreOffice support](https://help.libreoffice.org/Draw/Defining_Custom_Colors) page , printing in CMYK is not currently possible.

> ***LibreOffice uses only the RGB color model for printing in color. 
>       The CMYK controls are provided only to ease the input of color values using CMYK notation.***

To my knowledge, you will need to export the pdf using a tool like [pstill](http://www.pstill.com/) which does pdf conversion to either a PostScript(*.ps) or EPS(*.eps) format. The software is rather old; but it does run, for me, on a 12.04 machine.

There is also the [Gutenprint driver](http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/) that you may want to investigate. It appears to be a bit newer.

As far as the conversion process goes, I had seen a bit of a color-shift in document quality with pstill . YMMV, as my print jobs have not been color critical on Ubuntu.

Comment: Not FOSS, but *Adobe Acrobat Pro* and *Foxit PDF Editor* [are said to be able to convert color scheme to CMYK](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-pdf-cmyk-printers-57070.html).